# NIntegrate fails with functions that have (necessarily) numeric lists as arguments

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, compile

I'm not able to NIntegrate a function that has a numeric list as an argument. My original problem involves a compiled function, but a MWE is the following:

```
g[r : {__?NumericQ}, x_?NumericQ] := r;
NIntegrate[g[{2}, x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

This gives me the following error:

[image: error integrand is not numerical]

which I fail to understand, since

```
g[{2}, 0.0795732]
```

evaluates perfectly fine to {2}.

Other functions like Plot are fine, i.e. the following works as expected:

```
Plot[g[{2}, x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

Also, if we don't force the arguments to be numeric, i.e.:

```
gS[r_, x_] := r;
NIntegrate[gS[{2}, x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

everything works fine. But I do need to force them to be numeric because eventually I want to NIntegrate a compiled function. The example posted here is the simplest MWE I've been able to provide.

I would really appreciate any thoughts, since I'm quite lost here.
Thank you so much,
Luis

Comment: `{2}` is not a number

Comment: @CarlWoll.  I don't think that's the problem, because `NIntegrate[{2}, {x, 0, 1}]` evaluates just fine.  The issue is that in `NIntegrate[gS[{2}, x], {x, 0, 10}]`, the integrand won't evaluate to a number because `x` is not a number.  On the face of it, I wouldn't know how to short-circuit the evaluation here, because `Evaluate@gS[{2}, x]` of course yields `gS[{2}, x]`, but it needs to be evaluated before the `NIntegrate` so that {2} can integrate to {2.}. Luis, I suspect the thing that you are trying to do should be done in a different way.  Perhaps the greater context would be helpful.

Comment: @march, thank you so much for pointing that out. What I am trying to do is to NIntegrate each of the components of a compiled function that returns a list. Thanks to CarlWoll and you, I understand the problem much better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) requires the integrand to be numeric, and the list `{2}` is not numeric:

```
NumericQ[{2}]
```

> False

You need your function `g` to return something that is numeric, not a list.

*(aside: @march points out that:)*

```
NIntegrate[{2}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

> {2.}

*works fine, but that is because [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) recognizes that the first argument is a list and so it threads the first argument. One can see this happening using [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint):*

```
Trace @ NIntegrate[{2}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

> {NIntegrate[{2},{x,0,1}],{NIntegrate[2,{x,0,1}]},{NIntegrate[2,{x,0,1}],{{x}=.,{x=.},{x=.,Null},{Null}},{x=.,Null},2.},{2.}}

*Notice how `NIntegrate[{2}, {x, 0, 1}]` evaluates to `{NIntegrate[2, {x, 0, 1}]}`.*

Your other approach worked because [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) evaluated its first argument to a list, and then the default threading that happens when the first argument is a list took over.

So, you need to make sure the output of `g` is a number. For instance:

```
g[r:{__?NumericQ}, x_?NumericQ] := First @ r
NIntegrate[g[{2}, x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

> 20.

Comment: Thank you so much Carl and March, now I understand everything. Perfectly clear explanation, thanks a lot Guys!!!